# Javascript Inheritance (super)

Tags: javascript, inheritance, frontend, super

I was going through the JS inheritance documentation and I was greeted into a new "feature" (for me), called super, the keyword `super`. Well, from what I can understand, if I have a parent class called for example `hospitalStaff` with an argument of name and staff number and the inherited class is called `nurse` and also has the argument name on it but also other arguments. So, in this example I would just use `super(name);`, wouldn't I?

Thanks for helping!! Have a great day and happy coding!

Comment: `super` is used to call the parent class's constructor

Comment: well, you'd need name and staff number if that's what the parent class needs (by your own example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'd pass the parameters to the `super` function. By calling `super` in the `Nurse` constructor you call the constructor in the `HospitalStaff` and pass the parameters with them.

In the example below the `Nurse` class also has the `sayName` method. All methods (including the constructor) are inherited from the parent class.

But if your `Nurse` constructor is different than the one from `HospitalStaff` then you need to create a new constructor which also calls the constructor of the parent by using `super`. Without calling `super` you would just overwrite the child constructor. Try it out, it would still work. But you'll won't have the `name` and `staffNumber` properties.

Same goes for methods where you can use `super` to call methods from the parent. This way you can overwrite a method from the child but still keep parent's implementation of that method.

```js
class HospitalStaff {
  constructor(name, staffNumber) {
    this.name = name;
    this.staffNumber = staffNumber;
  }
  sayName() {
    console.log(`Name: ${this.name}`);
    console.log(`Number: ${this.staffNumber}`);
  }
}

class Nurse extends HospitalStaff {
  constructor(name, staffNumber, field) {
    super(name, staffNumber); // Sets name and staffNumber properties
    this.field = field; // Adds a field property
  }
  sayName() {
    super.sayName();
    console.log(`Field: ${this.field}`);
  }
}

const bob = new HospitalStaff('bob', 43);
bob.sayName();

const julie = new Nurse('Julie', 120, 'pediatrics');
julie.sayName();
```